Azure Kubernetes Service pod pending - 4 Insufficient cpu
i hope somebody can shade some light on this issue and how to solve it.
i have an Azure kubernetes service running on a FRee Tier with 2 worker nodes:

system node (vm
Standard_D2ds_v5), this is used for helm charts and has autoscaling enable to max 2 instance
Linux node (
Standard_D2ds_v5), this is the node i am using for all my deployments and can scale up to 6 instances

I am releasing about 40 pods in total and each pod has an istio sidecar.
Today i start seeing that after each release, the new pod get in status pending with message:
0/5 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector, 4 Insufficient cpu. preemption: 0/5 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling, 4 No preemption victims found for incoming pod..
I am a bit confused here because i cannot pin point exactly the issue.
Reading microsoft docs, i can see that there is a limit of 30pods per node, which mean i supposedly could have 180pods in total, 30 per node and 6 nodes in total on the linux worker scale set (right?)
If the issue is not the limit of pods running in the node, leaves me with the resource limitation and not setting the thresholds of how much resource each container can use.
i prepared this yaml file:
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: cpu-limit-range
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  limits:
  - default:
      cpu: "500m"
    defaultRequest:
      cpu: "250m"
    type: Container
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: cpu-limit-range
  namespace: default
spec:
  limits:
  - default:
      cpu: "500m"
    defaultRequest:
      cpu: "250m"
    type: Container

i applied the resource limit but nothing seems to change, i can see the limits if i describe the namespaces but pods keep being in pending status.
Just to clarify as i believe is important. the workers use the azure CNI network which limits to 30pods per node.
Please if anyone can help me understand what i am doing wrong here i will be grateful and if you need more information, dont hesitate to ask

Check the Azure Kubernetes Service Diagnose and Solve Problems - it might provide some information about this issue and maybe suggest a fix.

it seems that the issue is due to nodes not having enough CPU resources available. running 40 pods with Istio sidecars, could be consuming a significant amount of CPU resources. Can you add these to your thread- kubectl top nodes kubectl describe nodes and kubectl logs -n kube-system deployment/cluster-autoscaler

Nayden it just came to my mind what if the limit range you've applied is only for the kube-system and default namespaces, and it is possible that your pods are running in a different namespace. Can you check it once? You may have a taint on one of your nodes, which makes it ineligible for scheduling despite having free memory. You can find the taint and remove it. You can use kubectl describe nodes | grep -e 'Taint|Hostname' to find which of the two nodes have a taint. Check all these once, if all good then try removing the resource request and limit from the POD deployment file.

To resolve the issue of pending pods with insufficient CPU resources, you can try adjusting the CPU limits to a lower value and adding more worker nodes to your cluster.
You can refer to below example and compare it with your setup.
Here I have two nodes under my cluster navAKSCluster
System Node Pool-
az aks nodepool add \
  --resource-group navrg \
  --cluster-name navAKSCluster \
  --name systempool \
  --node-count 1 \
  --enable-cluster-autoscaler \
  --min-count 1 \
  --max-count 2 \
  --node-vm-size Standard_D2ds_v5 \
  --mode System


user pool
az aks nodepool add \
  --resource-group navrg \
  --cluster-name navAKSCluster \
  --name userpool \
  --node-count 1 \
  --enable-cluster-autoscaler \
  --min-count 1 \
  --max-count 6 \
  --node-vm-size Standard_D2ds_v5 \
  --mode User


applied resource Limits
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: cpu-limit-range
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  limits:
  - default:
      cpu: "500m"
    defaultRequest:
      cpu: "250m"
    type: Container
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: cpu-limit-range
  namespace: default
spec:
  limits:
  - default:
      cpu: "500m"
    defaultRequest:
      cpu: "250m"
    type: Container



and deployed an application
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "100m"
            memory: "200Mi"
          limits:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: "500Mi"



Now if you see, if I do
kubectl get pods -n default



or
kubectl top nodes



If you still face issues with pending pods due to CPU constraints, you can scale the node pool:
kubectl scale deployment nginx --replicas=20 -n default


Now verify
kubectl get pods -n default



you can even set up Horizontal Pod Autoscaling
kubectl autoscale deployment nginx --cpu-percent=50 --min=10 --max=50 -n default



References:

Best practices for application developers to manage resources in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)
Deployment and cluster reliability best practices for Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)
Tutorial - Scale applications in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)

